# jQuery DataTable - visible column

Tags: jquery, datatable

I have code:

```
$('#table').dataTable({
      "aoColumnDefs": [
                { "bVisible": true, "aTargets":[0], "mDataProp":"name" },
                { "bVisible": true, "aTargets":[1], "mDataProp":"surname" },
                { "bVisible": true, "aTargets":[2], "mDataProp":"number" }
      ]
    });
```

This code is display when I have variable `Search` set **true**, but when I have `Search` set **false** I want show only surname and number columns, how can I do that?

Comment: I don't understand, what do you mean?

Comment: Can you run a separate function to hide the columns if the search is false?

Comment: No, because I don't have separate function, because I don't want repeat the same code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
var Search = false;

$('#table').dataTable({
      "aoColumnDefs": [
                { "bVisible": function() { return Search; }, "aTargets":[0], "mDataProp":"name" },
                { "bVisible": true, "aTargets":[1], "mDataProp":"surname" },
                { "bVisible": true, "aTargets":[2], "mDataProp":"number" }
      ]
    });
```